# Edit existing inline javascript

Tags: javascript

Website has several thousand pages with inline javascript, that was copypasted manually to each page along with other content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  // Display Settings
  var eCAT_eID = "xxxxxxx"; // Your ID
  var eCAT_siteID = 0; // Your Site ID
  // Stop Editing
  var hz = ".com";
  var fz0 = "coridoonline" + hz + "/ebay/ebay_dynamic_cats/ebayCatsSA.php";
  var az = "SC";
  var bz = "RY";
  var cz = "PT";
  var dz = "SR";
  var ez = "C=";
  var fz = "htt";
  var gz = "p://";
  document.write("<" + az + bz + cz + " type='text/javascript'" + dz + ez + fz + gz + fz0 + "?eid=" + escape(eCAT_eID) + "&siteid=" + eCAT_siteID + ">");
  document.write("</" + az + bz + cz + ">");
                            -->
</script>
```

I see it's a kind of watermark by the one developed that website long ago. It creates another 'script' that refers to 'coridoonline.com' wich is now down. That causes a 20 sec delay in loading webpages because browsers are trying to reach it. Is there any way to fix it? Except removing this script from all the pages manually. 
Thank you in advance for any ideas and answers!

Comment: Hire a developer that can write a small script that opens all the files and edits out the scripts. Could be done in anything, like Perl, Python or Node or PHP really, or even right in the IDE

Comment: Have you thought about using a python, ruby, or bash script to search for that script in each of the files and then remote it?

Comment: Several thousand pages - but how many levels deep?

Comment: **Quentin, aus_lacy**, thank you for advice! Guess it's the best option.
**Rounin**, it is actually an online shop, so there are not many levels. The script is located at product description pages.

Answer (score 0):

Basically any IDE, even text editor as notepad++ will do that with the find&replace functionality. Paste the code you want to get rid of, search in whole project end replace with empty string.